# Referencing a Paypal payment with external id

Tags: php, paypal

There might be some cases where a payment can be successfully authorized by the client and due to client's network, the response might not reach our return URL and we are unaware of paypal's payment ID.

To capture such payments, Is there a way of sending a reference ID to paypal while creating a payment and querying the payments based on that reference ID.

Comment: Id suggest a bit more research before posting: does the answer exist in teh [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/reference/)

Comment: @spacepickle Did go through their documentation. Couldn't find such a feature with their REST APIs. Thats why posted if anyone does know a way of doing it or if anyone has done it